# Lambda functions with "=" capture and memory usage

Tags: c++, memory, lambda

In my mind when I create a lambda `[=]{...}` all variables from parent function clones to the lambda.

So the following code will use too much memory because variables a...z will be copied to lambda function:

```
void foo() {
    long double a = 0.123456789;
    long double b = 0.123456789;
    long double c = 0.123456789;
    //.... 
    long double z = 0.123456789;

    auto val = [=]() {return a+z;};
}
```

Is not it?

Comment: You only use `a` and `z` in your lambda expression, so only these two variables will be copied. All other variables are not captured and thus not copied.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[=]` will cause only the variables that are actually used in the lambda to be captured by it.

In your case `val` will have a copy of `a` and `z`. Assuming there is no padding (which there shouldn't be), then `sizeof(val) == 2*sizeof(long double)`.

Comment: Relevant extra reading: [**expr.prim.lambda.capture**](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda.capture#7.3)